# Line length limit in F# - Bug or feature?

Tags: f#

This code gives you an error in the error list of VS 2010:

```
let (a: float), (b: float), (c: int), (d: float), (e: float), (f: float), (g: float), (h: float), (i: float), (j: float), (k: float), (l: float), (abcdefghijklmnopqrstabcdefghijklmnopqrstabc: float ) = 0., 0., 0, 0., 0., 0., [], 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.
```

Adding one character to the last variable as

```
let (a: float), (b: float), (c: int), (d: float), (e: float), (f: float), (g: float), (h: float), (i: float), (j: float), (k: float), (l: float), (abcdefghijklmnopqrstabcdefghijklmnopqrstabcd: float ) = 0., 0., 0, 0., 0., 0., [], 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.
```

results in no error in the error list.

I have met such a behaviour in many ways but always in the long lines only. Is that a feature of F# or is it a bug?

Oldrich

Comment: The error is still there even in the second one (if you try build, you'll see it). It's just that Visual Studio doesn't provide the red squigglies for it in the second (When 256 columns are reached).

Comment: I've had similar errors probably caused by the same bug in the F# compiler. I just wanted to paste some F#-compatible data I'd output to a text file into F# interactive and couldn't get it to work until I wrote my own code to parse and pretty print it across many lines. This is a really insane bug, IMHO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using VS2010 shell with the November CTP (not really sure whether this new CTP was built against .NET 2.0 or .NET 4.0)

I've tested this code in a various scenarios, and there is something a bit strange going on here. But certainly there are no "features" at work here, since as @Mauricio pointed out, both of these let-bindings are incorrect.

### Interactive

Both give (almost) correct error to output:

> Expecting a
>       float * float * int * float * float * float * float * float * float
>   * float * float * float * float     but given a
>       float * float * int * float * float * float * float * float * float
>   * float * float * float * float * 'a     The tuples have differing lengths of
>   13 and 14

Notice the "given" part of the error is wrong.

### On-the-fly Error Detection Within VS Editor

Here I am seeing behavior similar to what you describe: I created two files Program.fs and Program2.fs with top-level modules `test1` and `test2` containing your first and second examples respectively. I get a red-squigly(sp?) with the same error message we had in FSI for the first, but no red-squigly for the second (and by toggling the 'd' character in the second I was able to induce the red-squigly).

### Compiling

When attempting to build the project in the previous example, I get build errors for both let-bindings (same as what we see through FSI).

### Conclusion

So it does look like there are two bugs (minor since we can't actually build the project) here:

1. The error message is incorrect
2. The in-editor error detection is inconsistent

Answer (score 4):

The Visual Studio F# support cannot do errors and squiggles past column 255.  If you look at the F# `range` type in the compiler sources, you can perhaps start to glean why (though I think it really should to go at least 511 chars); I don't remember for 100% sure right now exactly where the limitation lies.

(Incidentally, I only know this because I recently ran into it, see the comment at

https://github.com/brianmcn/FSharpDepthColorizer/blob/master/ParseTreeDepth/MyFSParser/MyParsing.fs

line 267.)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio provides the red squiggles and error navigation based on the position information returned from the F# compiler (fsc.exe). Unfortunately, as of VS2010 SP1, the F# compiler does not provide position information for errors in far right columns. You can see this in the Visual Studio Output Window. Normally an error shows up like this:

> File.fs(60,213): error FS0001: This expression was expected ...

If the column isn't 213, but rather something larger (above 255 I think), the error is reported like this (and you get to have happy fun finding it):

> File.fs: error FS0001: This expression was expected ...